# Fusedav autostarting strange permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, webdav

I try to set up automatic mounting of remote disk using fusedav.

I use this command to mount it.

```
/usr/bin/fusedav -u user_name -p 'secret_password' https://webdav.yandex.com
/home/user/ya
```

If I am logged in it and execute this command it works fine.

I tried  to move this command to autostart. 
  I put this line into file `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` what is destined for it.
  Command gets executed but when I try to go to this folder /home/user/ya I get error something like "can't access directory".

I checked its permissions

[image]

Very strange and confusing. Any ideas what could be the root of the problem?

Notes:

I try to mount the directory what I own.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  I tried to launch it as nohup command &

and got such output in nohup file:

fusermount: failed to open /etc/fuse.conf: Permission denied
PROPFIND failed: 404 Object Not Found
PROPFIND failed: 404 Object Not Found
PROPFIND failed: 404 Object Not Found
PROPFIND failed: 404 Object Not Found
PROPFIND failed: 404 Object Not Found
PROPFIND failed: 404 Object Not Found
*** Caught signal ***

The last line shows that something killed fusedav. 
No idea why and why anyway.